# subprocess intermittently returns empty

Tags: python, macos, subprocess, stdout

I'm running a subprocess in python3, on Mac OS to retrieve the EXIF image data from a number of images saved on a local directory.

The code works intermittently. Ruffly every 3rd call the subprocess returns the byte object (as expected), only it is empty b''.

The failure is not specific to any particular image file (changes).

I've tried two versions of the code, one where the Popen.wait(..) is called (example finding the latitude below) and another where .communicate() is called immediately (example finding the longitude below).

```
print('.......========.......')
try:
    cmdLat = "mdls \"" + imagePath + "\" | grep Latitude | awk '{print $3}'"
    subprocess = Popen(cmdLat, shell=True, stdout=PIPE)
    Popen.wait(subprocess)
    lat = subprocess.communicate()[0]
    latFloat = float(lat.decode())
except Exception as e:
    print("Failed finding latitude, exception:", e)
    print("lat value: ", lat)

try:
    cmdLon = "mdls \"" + imagePath + "\" | grep Longitude | awk '{print $3}'"
    lon = (Popen(cmdLon, shell=True, stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0])
    lonFloat = float(lon.decode())
except Exception as e:
    print("Failed finding longitude, exception:", e)
    print("lon value: ", lat)
```

Attempt 1 Results:

```
.......========.......
IMG_0149.JPG has been successful
.......========.......
IMG_0161.JPG has been successful
.......========.......
IMG_0377.JPG has been successful
.......========.......
Failed finding latitude, exception: could not convert string to float:
lat value:  b''
Failed finding longitude, exception: could not convert string to float:
lon value:  b''
```

Attempt 2 Results:

```
.......========.......
IMG_0149.JPG has been successful
.......========.......
IMG_0161.JPG has been successful
.......========.......
IMG_0377.JPG has been successful
.......========.......
IMG_0007.JPG has been successful
.......========.......
Failed finding lattitude, exception: could not convert string to float:
lat value:  b''
Failed finding longitude, exception: could not convert string to float:
lon value:  b''
```

Comment: Just a wild guess: The commands connected by pipes run in parallel and maybe the shell call ends when mdls terminates without waiting for the rest.

Comment: why indent after the first line?

Comment: Have you tried to run the command `mdls` manually on those files that failed? It could be that they don't contain any EXIF information.

Comment: first post - sorry for the formatting. Yes, i've tried running any failed file names independently and they work fine. often the same file on two different attempts to run will work the second time - definitely not an issue with the files in conclusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be the way you quote the file names that causes trouble, or it could be the timing as Michael Butscher suggested. I have tried to write a solution myself and found that most of my pictures are without coordinates.

Here is my solution, please let me know if it works for you. Note that for those pictures without the coordinates, `lat=="(null)"` and `lon="(null)"`. For those that do have the coordinates, `lat` and `lon` will be floating points.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import pathlib
import subprocess

def main():
    """ Entry """
    for pic_file in pathlib.Path('.').glob('*.jpg'):
        print('-' * 72)
        print(pic_file)
        command = ['mdls',
                   '-name', 'kMDItemLatitude',
                   '-name', 'kMDItemLongitude',
                   str(pic_file)]
        output = subprocess.check_output(command, encoding='utf-8')
        # Sample output
        #    kMDItemLatitude  = (null)
        #    kMDItemLongitude = (null)
        # or
        #    kMDItemLatitude  = 46.75725833333333
        #    kMDItemLongitude = -71.28605666666667        
        print(output)

        # Parse the output
        lines = output.splitlines()
        values = [line.split()[-1] for line in lines]
        print(values)

        # Convert to float
        try:
            lat, lon = [float(value) for value in values]
        except ValueError:
            lat, lon = values

        print('Latitude =', lat)
        print('Logitude =', lon)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

## Notes

- I don't use the `grep` and `awk` commands as I want to parse the values myself
- Normally, the output from the `subprocess` functions will return raw byte array, I use `encoding='utf-8'` to convert that to Python 3 strings.

Comment: Works perfectly thanks! I'm assuming the original issue may lie in the subprocess calls to grep and awk since the .subprocess.check_output change didn't work in isolation either.

Comment: On further testing the problem remains - albeit it occurs far far less often (once every 50 entries as opposed to every 3rd). Specifically, the subprocess will intermittently return null in the mdls query when a value exists. Again, the same file will work on another occasion. For my purposes this solution is enough (I can check for failure and rerun until it works) - should I leave this as the marked solution?

Comment: That is a strange problem, I don't know if it is related to timing or not. Try to put a second sleep in between the files to see if it helps.